# Parenthesis and brackets when calling gradle task method

Tags: gradle

Gradle API declares the following method on the project instance:

`Task task​(Map<String,​?> args,String name) throws InvalidUserDataException`

My understanding is that when declaring the name of the task, the "name" parameter according to the signature above must be inside the parentesis (). However, I see the following script and I know it is legitimate:

```
task printVersion(group: 'versioning', description: 'Prints project version.') << {
  logger.quiet "Version: $version"
}
```

Question1: Assuming that I refer to the correct method signature, why is it possible to have the "name" parameter outside of the parenthesis and only the map attributes inside them?

Question2: Maps in groovy are defined by [key1:value1, key2:value2]. Why are we allowed to skip the brackets defining the map in the call above i.e. [group:'versioning,description:'Prints project version'] ?

What magic in gradle or groovy allows us to deviate so much from the signature of the method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it is both Groovy and Gradle magic at the same time. Let's look at the Groovy part first.

Groovy supports named method parameters, somewhat similar to languages Python, Kotlin, or C# (later versions). In Groovy, the method signature needs to start with a Map, which holds the named parameters. Any number of "positional" parameters can be added after that.

An example given in the [official Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_named_parameters_2) is:

```java
def foo(Map args, Integer number) { "${args.name}: ${args.age}, and the number is ${number}" }
foo(name: 'Marie', age: 1, 23)  
foo(23, name: 'Marie', age: 1)
```

The positional parameters can be anywhere relative to the named ones.

I don't personally like that this notation hides the declaration of named parameters, but I assume this is the best viable solution when Groovy also needs to have very high compatibility with Java.

The second Groovy magic part is that parentheses are optional when there is no ambiguity. An example is the `logger.quiet` part of your code.

But all this still doesn't explain in your example how we can write 'printVersion' outside the parentheses when in plain Groovy it should have been `task('printVersion', group: 'versioning', description: 'Prints project version.')`.

It works because Gradle has a special Groovy compiler plugin that transforms the method call to read nicer in a Gradle build script. I don't know much about it, but the source code for it is [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/b6041c4f6143fc0e35997c12c8d3b64b29f3e7e6/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/groovy/scripts/internal/TaskDefinitionScriptTransformer.java).

This is another thing I personally don't like - that it can be rather difficult to figure out how these things work and what you can do with them. But in Gradle's defense, this is the only very weird construct I know of, and it is not even recommended anymore.

In newer versions of Gradle, you will instead define a task as:

```java
tasks.register("printVersion") {
    group = "versioning"
    description = "Prints project version."

    doLast {
        logger.quiet "Version: $version"
    }
}
```

This has the following advantages over the old way:

- No [DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html) magic anymore - you are now calling a normal Java method called [register](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html#register-java.lang.String-org.gradle.api.Action-) on the [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getTasks--) property (Groovy allows you to write `tasks` instead of `getTasks()`).
- Is lazy so you don't spend time configuring the task if it is not going to be executed.
- No more funky `<<` left-shift operators that no one knew how to use correctly in the first place (it was also deprecated all the way back in Gradle 3.2)
- Works in both Groovy and Kotlin DSL.

Comment: Thank you kindly Bjørn Vester for your comment! It is much appreciated!