# Syntax in Gradle using Groovy

Tags: gradle, groovy, syntax

Recently learning gradle, and using groovy as the dsl.

but i am confused about some syntax in task, as shown below

```
task mytask {
  doLast {
    println("my task")
  }
}
```

here task accepting 2 arguments, using the signature `Task task(String var1, Closure var2);`

But in groovy, we need comma to separate 2 arguments pass into a function. Why it is not the case in gradle?
Or I have some misunderstanding?

Comment: I wrote an answer to a similar question that might help you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68587197/1703730. The TL;DR is that Gradle has a special compiler plugin to allow that syntax, but you probably also shouldn't use that syntax anymore anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally understood